# Transactional and Bulk Email Workflow

Tags: node.js, email, mailchimp, mailgun

What are the best practices for using both transactional and marketing email?

Currently I am testing Mailgun for transactional email due to their free API which fits my usage, and once scaled, has balanced pricing plans. This is compared to Mandrill, which recently became a pay-only service. However, Mandrill's parent product - Mailchimp - seems ideal for newsletters, and does have a free version with PAYG payment options which is also balanced for my needs.

The problem is this: I can already create and subscribe clients to lists within Mailgun. However, it appears there is no easy web-interface to send emails in bulk (eg. newsletters). Although I have not yet tried Mailchimp, I hear they do have an interface. This leads me to believe that if I use Mailgun for bulk email, I need to send it through my website server (as an approved domain). In order to do this, I then either need to create a script I can SSH into and call on an email file, or, I need to create an admin page for sending newsletters. This is additional complexity, and I am not sure if this is correct usage, or if there is a better option. Ideally, I wish to combine both transactional and bulk mailing services together, and use a web interface via this service's website for bulk emailing if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Email senders like Sendgrid, Sparkpost, Amazon SES are well-known as bulk senders and suitable to handle bulk volume emails.Some of them have both front end and APIs available to support transactional emails. However as per my opinion Transactional emails require exclusivity.

I would recommend you to avoid the same provider for both Transactional and Bulk messages to secure your investment in mailing solution and prevent brand reputation. The major ESPs such as Gmail, Yahoo, Apple, Hotmail ranks and treat sender reputations based on sending pattern and infrastructure.

We have seen cases, where companies lost their brand reputation due to failing in segregating infrastructure between Bulk and Transactional.

You can have a look on EasySendy Pro, Mailchimp, and Campaignmonitor for your promotional/marketing emails.

One should never compare Transactional and Promotional emails on the price front. It's like comparing Apple to Oranges. Of course, the ROI is an unavoidable factor here. Transactional emails have the highest open rates in the industry (up to 78% in some cases) and are more engaging to customers.

For transactional email, you must give a thought on the reliable solutions like Aritic Mail or Postmark, as they are the pure transactional emailing system and designed exclusively for the same purpose.

- Rahul Singh